# InstallAnywhere - Managing application's file permissions for Admin/non-admin users in WIndows

Tags: windows-installer, uac, installanywhere

I am new to InstallAnywhere and still on the learning path.

How can I achieve the file permissions on the application directory so that only Administrator
has Full Control over all the files and non-Admin does not have even Read (R) permissions, apart from log files where read can be granted?

Just like what chmod 700 and 744 achieves in linux.

Is there any way in InstallAnywhere by which this can be achieved?

Out of desperation i tried icacls but to no avail. All the files of the application are either owned by Administrator or System.

Thanks in Advance,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is that application folder you are referring to? Folders (like the Program Files folder) already have some of those restrictions, but beware that if you make too many limitations users won't be able to run programs from there (the "Read and Execute" permission).

Comment: Hi @PhilDW, suppose my application name is ABC and it installs under C:\Program Files\ABC - so all the files & folders under ABC, i want to restrict to Administrators only, any other user will not even have Read permissions apart from log files. The application mostly contains sensitive data, hence this requirement/restriction.

Comment: You'll need to use Permissions to make those files restricted to admins - I'm not familiar with InstallAnywhere so I don't know what built-in functionality it might have to do that.